# No href with Link In React-router

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, hyperlink, href, react-router

I'm facing a very strange behaviour with React-Router. Following is the code of my component in React:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link} from 'react-router'

export default class LinkWidget extends React.Component {
render()
  {
    return (
        <li>
          <Link className="page-scroll" to={"#" + this.props.path}>{this.props.name}</Link>
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

On its rendering, i'm getting the following HTML, i.e, an anchor tag without href property.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This is happening in other components as well. I know i'm missing something out but i have no clue what it is. I/m a newbie trying React and React Router. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks is advance :)

**----Update----**

Here is what my react components look like (Using the React Developer tools) :

[image: LinkWidget]

I'm doing something wrong here but what i can't get.

**Update 2**

I'm following the container-component pattern and could it be possible that i'm somehow writing the route file wrong. Though i can't understand why would it be a problem when i'm passing static data.

Can someone guide me with routing using the container-component pattern.

Comment: is your this.props.path prop properly coming from the parent? Can you print and check once? Also can you share your parent component once from which props are passed to LinkWidget

Comment: The props are being returned properly @HarkiratSaluja. I checked it out again.

Comment: @Aakanksha How about if you use this `to={\`#${this.props.path}\`}` ?

Comment: @KienThanh, No luck with it as well. I have updated the question, hope it gives an idea about whats going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple in your `to attribute in Lin`k do not add a `"#"`. Link attribute conversion is such that it adds a `#/` to the anchor href automatically.

Use:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link} from 'react-router'

export default class LinkWidget extends React.Component {
render()
  {
    return (
        <li>
          <Link className="page-scroll" to={this.props.path}>{this.props.name}</Link>
        </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the link of an example fiddle where I tested this functionality

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mana88Lm/20/)

Comment: I tried this as well but it still renders anchor in the same way without the href prop.

Comment: @Aakanksha could you check the value of this.props.path

Comment: Yes, i get the 'this.props.path'. I have updated the question, please have a look at it. I might be missing something really small.